# Calls to google places Api stops working after a few calls until the next day. Api Exception 13

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

I've been searching the net like crazy to find an answer to no avail.

My problem is that after I test my app a few times it suddenly stops working. At first I get Api exception 10, then the second time I debug I get Api Exception 13. There seems to be a problem related to the google places API. The first calls returns the results as intended, but after that I cant make any calls at all. Then suddenly it starts wokring again then stops working again. I've checked the quotas on the Api console and they are fine.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1

    val mDatabase : DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("menus");
    val mGeoDataClient = getGeoDataClient(this);
    val mPlaceDetectionClient : PlaceDetectionClient = Places.getPlaceDetectionClient(this);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            Toast.makeText(this, "The app needs access to Locations to function properly.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)


        }
    } else {
        // Permission has already been granted
    }

    val placeResult = mPlaceDetectionClient.getCurrentPlace(null)
    placeResult.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        val likelyPlaces = task.result

        for (placeLikelihood in likelyPlaces) {
            Log.i("Plats", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                    placeLikelihood.place.name,
                    placeLikelihood.likelihood))
        }
        var place = likelyPlaces[0].place

        val tv_place : TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_place) as TextView;
        tv_place.text = place.name;

        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                // ...
                Log.i("HEJ", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString())

                val t = object : GenericTypeIndicator<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards Menu>>() {

                }
                val menus = dataSnapshot.getValue(t)!!
                lateinit var menu: Menu;
                for(m in menus) {
                    if (m.name == place.name) {
                        menu = m;
                    }
                }
                var tv_menu : TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_menu) as TextView
                if (menu != null) tv_menu.text = menu.items[0].name
            }


            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                // ...
            }

        })
        likelyPlaces.release()
    }
}
```

}

```
04-03 10:14:33.537 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source:85)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:117)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:28)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1963)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1938)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:23)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6545)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6015)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1756)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzebe;
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzj.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source:19)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source:85) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:117) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:28) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1963) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1938) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:23) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6094) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6015) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1756) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzebe" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzj.<init>(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source:19) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:0) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source:85) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:117) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:28) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1963) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1938) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:23) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6094) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6015) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1756) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
04-03 10:14:33.538 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu E/FirebaseApp:     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:686)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:719)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:947)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2290)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.schedulePreload(ActivityThread.java:1494)
        at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub.onTransact(IApplicationThread.java:1092)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:692)
04-03 10:14:33.612 32580-21664/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzecz;
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:207)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zze.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzecz;
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzbuz(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecz" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzbuz(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu-kypQva0apmYdyCID8LfrOQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:686)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:719)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:947)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2290)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.schedulePreload(ActivityThread.java:1494)
        at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub.onTransact(IApplicationThread.java:1092)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:692)
04-03 10:14:33.614 32580-21665/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu E/FirebaseCrash: Failed waiting for crash api to load.
    java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1063)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1352)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:278)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zzbut(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zza.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
04-03 10:14:33.659 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
04-03 10:14:33.661 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
04-03 10:14:33.664 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-03 10:14:33.688 32580-32585/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=21KB
    After code cache collection, code=28KB, data=21KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
04-03 10:14:33.689 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 1254567931
04-03 10:14:33.709 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Collection enabled
    App package, google app id: nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu, 1:716909307411:android:b3fce941d6b0cce7
04-03 10:14:33.710 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12211
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu
04-03 10:14:33.710 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
04-03 10:14:33.738 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Connecting to remote service
04-03 10:14:33.752 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-03 10:14:33.766 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: onActivityCreated
04-03 10:14:33.803 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/BoostFramework: mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
04-03 10:14:33.927 32580-21671/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
04-03 10:14:33.930 32580-21671/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
04-03 10:14:33.966 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Activity resumed, time: 61262918
04-03 10:14:33.971 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
04-03 10:14:33.973 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu D/AppTracker: App Event: start
04-03 10:14:33.975 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8631030232630638994}]
04-03 10:14:33.991 32580-21671/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
04-03 10:14:34.009 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-03 10:14:34.086 32580-21674/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
04-03 10:14:34.099 32580-32596/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8996.so from the current namespace instead.
04-03 10:14:34.113 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu D/FA: Connected to remote service
04-03 10:14:34.114 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
04-03 10:14:39.192 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
04-03 10:14:43.974 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Session started, time: 61272926
04-03 10:14:44.000 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8631030232630638994}]
04-03 10:14:44.042 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-03 10:14:44.044 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu, PID: 32580
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.getResult(Unknown Source:14)
        at nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onComplete(MainActivity.kt:73)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:23)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzz(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzr(Unknown Source:32)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zzc(Unknown Source:81)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(Unknown Source:34)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.places.zzm.zzbk(Unknown Source:63)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzy.onTransact(Unknown Source:69)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:692)
04-03 10:14:44.047 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu E/UncaughtException: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.getResult(Unknown Source:14)
        at nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onComplete(MainActivity.kt:73)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:23)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzz(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzr(Unknown Source:32)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zzc(Unknown Source:81)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(Unknown Source:34)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.places.zzm.zzbk(Unknown Source:63)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzy.onTransact(Unknown Source:69)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:692)
04-03 10:14:44.049 32580-32580/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
04-03 10:14:44.059 32580-21666/nilsson.gattanjo.dmenu V/FA: Connecting to remote service
```

Comment: you sure you aren't running into daily limits? I think places has a daily limit of free 1000 calls and then you can only use it if you have billing enabled for your account

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/usage

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/issues/73 try this, might be some other issue like wrong setup too